# Calculate $\mathbb{E}\left[ f(S-y(t+E)) e^{-rE}\right]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\lambda, \mu > 0$ and assume $n(t)$ is a Poisson Process with parameter $\mu$, further assume we have some i.i.d. sequence $(\xi_n)_n$ and define the compound Poisson process:
$$
N(t) = \sum_{i \leq n(t)} \xi_i \qquad t \geq 0.
$$
For some $D > 0$ we define the process $(y(t))_t$ by:
$$
y(t) = Dt + N(t).
$$
Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable, convex function with $f(0) = 0$.

Let $E$ be an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$ and $r,t > 0$. I would now like to have an expression for:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[  f(S-y(t+E)) e^{-rE}\right]
$$